# Login form using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a login form using PowerShell script. but it shows error. Script need to validate the user name and password. If the matches then write output ok.

Error:-

The property 'UsernameChar' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At D:\PS Script Source\Working projects\Login form.ps1:43 char:1

- $CTRL_username.Username = '*'
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
  ```

````
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$username        = "Test1"
$password        = "Test"
$script:isMatch  = $false

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Visible = $false
[void]$form.SuspendLayout()
$form.Text = 'Password Window'
$form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,220) 
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle

$CTRL_label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$CTRL_label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50) 
$CTRL_label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$CTRL_label1.Text = 'Please enter password:'
$CTRL_label1.Name = 'Label1'
[void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_label1) 

$CTRL_password = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$CTRL_password.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70) 
$CTRL_password.PasswordChar = '*'
$CTRL_password.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,20) 
$CTRL_password.MaxLength = 20
$CTRL_password.Name = 'Password'
[void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_password) 


$CTRL_label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$CTRL_label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10) 
$CTRL_label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$CTRL_label3.Text = 'Please enter username:'
$CTRL_label3.Name = 'Label3'
[void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_label3) 

$CTRL_username = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$CTRL_username.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30) 
$CTRL_username.UsernameChar = '*'
$CTRL_username.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,20) 
$CTRL_username.MaxLength = 20
$CTRL_username.Name = 'Password'
[void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_username) 

$CTRL_label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$CTRL_label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10) 
$CTRL_label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$CTRL_label2.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red
$CTRL_label2.Text = ''
$CTRL_label2.Name = 'Label2'
[void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_label2) 

$CTRL_Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CTRL_Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,90)
$CTRL_Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,23)
$CTRL_Button.Text = 'OK'
$CTRL_Button.Name = 'OK'

$CTRL_Button.Add_Click( { 

    if ( $CTRL_password.Text.Trim() -ceq $password ) {
        $script:isMatch = $true
        [void]$form.Close()
        [void]$form.Dispose()
    }
    else {
        $CTRL_label2.Text = 'wrong password!'
    }


 } )
[void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_Button)

[void]$form.ResumeLayout()

$userInput = $form.ShowDialog()

if( $script:isMatch ) {
    # do anything => passwort is ok!
    "OK!"
}```
````

Comment: Just like the error states: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox doesn't have a property named "userNameChar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because the TextBox-control does not have a property with the name "UsernameChar". I suspect that the code have been copied from above, when creating the textbox for password.

I also noticed that you have given both "CTRL_password" and "CTRL_username" the name "Password". This can be problematic when calling controls in other scenarios.

And another thing, the tab order for the form is created sequentially when adding the controls to the form. So the tab order is:

- Textbox for password
- Textbox for username
- Button

This can be confusing for the user, so my tip is to add the textbox for username first.